# Mock Redis for unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, stackexchange.redis

So this is my connection string

```
 public class RedisConnectorHelper
    {
        static RedisConnectorHelper()
        {
            RedisConnectorHelper.lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
             {
                 string redisServer = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedisServer"];
                 return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(redisServer+ ",allowAdmin=true");
             }, System.Threading.LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly);
        }

        private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection;

        public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection
        {
            get
            {
                return lazyConnection.Value;
            }
        }
    }
```

And my unit test which tests for the divisions method which has been implemented to store the redis cache value but here I couldn't figure out how to mock redis for unit test as this test method is directly trying to make connection with the redis on the pipeline as well as local environment.

```
     [Test]
        public void GetDivisons()
        {
            var mockDatabase = new Mock<StackExchange.Redis.IDatabase>();

            var mockMultiplexer = new Mock<StackExchange.Redis.IConnectionMultiplexer>();
            var result = _notebookService.GetDivisons();
            Assert.NotNull(result);
        }
```

Comment: We are using **LeanTest** which found it good solution for mocking external dependencies to have better unit tests which are cheaper and easy to maintain. 

you can find the Documentation [Here](https://github.com/belgaard/Leantest)

Answer (score 0):

Redis can be thought of as an implementation of a cache service.
You could

1. create a new cache interface
2. create an implementation of the interface that uses Redis
3. inject this new dependency into the class with business logic

This allows writing unit tests for class with business logic.
In order to test the Redis-based implementation of the cache service, component tests should be written and a running instance of Redis is required in this case.

Or you could start a TCP server that would imitate the Redis server but that is a bad solution for several reasons. For example, it requires knowing some details about the Redis server.